# How I do DirectCast on Wizard Control to sql?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net, wizard

I try using wizard control, I've 5 step on my wizard. I want to store my data when user clik finish button but I've some problem with store the data into sql. Here my code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Wizard1SDS" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tr9DbConn %>"
    InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [tr9_detail_eval] ([response_text]) VALUES (@txb_answer1)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="txb_answer1" Type="String" ControlID="txb_answer1" PropertyName="Text"/>
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my code behind :

```
Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(sender As Object, e As WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick
    Dim Wizard1SDS As SqlDataSource = DirectCast(Me.Wizard1.WizardSteps(0).FindControl("Wizard1SDS"), SqlDataSource)
    Wizard1SDS.Insert()

End Sub
```

my textbox code on wizard :

```
 <div style="margin : 10px;">
                      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txb_answer1" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="10" Rows="50" Height="123px" Width="600px" CssClass="step1" />
                 </div>
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oT77.png)

Any suggestion ? Thank You,

Comment: Waht is the error message you get? *I've some problem* is not a sufficient description...

Comment: sorry, I'm forget to add error message. This's I get went I try to click button finnish, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: So you have to figure out which object is nothing. Debug your code and check every object in your FiniSshButtonClick (Me, Wizard1, WizardSteps(0), FindControl("Wizard1SDS"))

Comment: I cant debug on my computer, I not use local db but a company server db. I try to change like this "Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Wizard1.FindControl("WizardStep1").FindControl("txb_answer1"), TextBox)" but still no stored data to sql. 

note : no error detect, just cant store into sql

Comment: The exception is being thrown by your code, not by the database.  If you're developing on your local machine, you can most certainly debug the code.  Put a breakpoint on the method and inspect the values to see which one is null - `Wizard1SDS` is null, so something in the preceding line was most likely the offending culprit.

Comment: On further reflection, why are you trying to find the `SqlDataSource`?  Why not simply do `Me.Wizard1SDS.Insert()`?

Comment: of course I try to debug my code but still no data is entered into my db. I've included all the details and the code of the image above, please see it sir.

Comment: Because I'm using SqlDataSource to stored the data into my db sir, you can see my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve my problem with this code behind, I replace DirectCast become CType and cast the textbox to string then findcontrol textbox. Here's my code :

```
Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(sender As Object, e As WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick


    Dim txb_answer1 As String = CType(Me.Wizard1.WizardSteps(0).FindControl("txb_answer1"), TextBox).Text
    Wizard1SDS.Insert()
    Response.Redirect("Eval.aspx")

End Sub
```